# Animate webkit scrollbar thumb background-color

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, scrollbar

I need to fade the `background-color` of scrollbars from `transparent` to `#333` when the page loads. I can't animate the `overflow` property even though I merely want to change it from `hidden` to `auto` because of superficial reasons imposed on designers/developers.

Unfortunately I can't seem to figure out how to do this using just CSS.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
@keyframes intro_scrollbars_webkit
{
 from {background-color: transparent;}
 to {background-color: #333;}
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
 -webkit-border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
 animation-delay: 200ms; 
 animation-duration: 1s; 
 animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
 animation-name: intro_scrollbars_webkit; 
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

Gecko (Waterfox, Pale Moon and Firefox) works perfectly:

```
@keyframes intro_scrollbars_standard
{
 from {scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;}
 to {scrollbar-color: #333 #000;}
}

*
{
animation-delay: 200ms; 
animation-duration: 1s; 
animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
animation-name: intro_scrollbars_standard; 
scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
}
```

Absolutely no JavaScript, frameworks, libraries, etc.